# Responsive images / browser screen ratio

Tags: image, browser, screen, fluid

I've come across this website: http://ethanmarcotte.com/ and when you scale the page down to tablet size, the logo which is Ethan Marcotte is in perfect ratio when the screen size gets bigger and smaller.

How would I go about replicating the same idea, having an image that is the same perspective no matter what screen resolution or what size the browser window is that it's being rendered on?

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
   max-width: 100%
}
```

If you want that this only happens at smaller resolutions you can add this and style the image between this.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

}
```